# Как открывать модально окно по клику на элемент с определённым классом?

Tags: javascript

Модально окно работает по клику на элемент с определённым id, а как открывать его по клику на элемент с определённым классом?

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modalWindow");
var btn = document.getElementById("modalBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modal__close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```
  <div class="modal-trigger">
    <div class="button">
      <button id="modalBtn" class="button__active"><?php the_field( 'program_btn' ); ?></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-trigger">
    <div class="button">
      <button id="modalBtn" class="button__active"><?php the_field( 'program_btn' ); ?></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
/* modal */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modal__container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color: #F9F4F0;
  z-index: 11;
}
.modal__header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.modal__title {
    font-weight: 500;
}
.modal__close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 13px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
    color: #747474;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal__close:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.modal-trigger {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #aa653c;
  z-index: -1;
}
.button__active {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: 1px solid $main-color;
    border-radius: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
    background-color: #dc834e;
    color: #F9F4F0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button__active:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

Comment: А что такое `modal` и `span` в JS?

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/rf2xnchg/